# Prove by contrapositive. If $xy \leq 0$, then $(x \geq 0$ and $y \leq 0)$ or $(x \leq 0$ and $y \geq 0)$

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Contrapositive: If $xy > 0$, then $(x < 0$ or $y > 0)$ and $(x > 0$ or $y < 0)$
For proof by contrapositive, I know I have to show $xy>0$. Here's what I have so far:
$$(x<0~\text{or}~y>0)~\text{and}~(x>0~\text{or}~y<0)$$
By distribution:
$$(x<0~\text{and}~x>0)~\text{or}~(y>0~\text{and}~x>0)~\text{or}~(x<0~\text{and}~y<0)~\text{or}~(y>0~\text{and}~y<0)$$
I get lost here because the first and fourth cases are contradictions but I know the second and third satisfy $xy>0$. How do I deal with $(x<0~\text{and}~x>0)$ and $(y>0~\text{and}~y<0)$?

Answer (score 1):

$$(x<0~\text{and}~x>0)~\text{or}~(y>0~\text{and}~x>0)~\text{or}~(x<0~\text{and}~y<0)~\text{or}~(y>0~\text{and}~y<0)$$

is equivalent to

$$(y>0~\text{and}~x>0)~\text{or}~(x<0~\text{and}~y<0)$$

as the first and fourth case are false, they can be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show $A\vee B\vee C\vee D{\implies}E$ where $E$ is $(xy>0)$, and $A,B,C,D$ are all the things you listed.  You now need to do a Proof by Cases.

$A\vee B\vee C\vee D$ is true when *at least one* among them holds.  You know two are *always* false, however, you do **not** need not show that *any are* true; rather you need to show that **all entail** $xy>0$.  A contradiction entails anything, by the principle of explosion. So you are halfway done.

- In the case of $x<0$ and $x>0$, we have a contradiction, so $xy>0$ by explosion.
- In the case of $y>0$ and $y<0$, we have a contradiction, so $xy>0$ by explosion.
- In the case of $y>0$ and $x>0$, then *for some reason*: $xy>0$.
- In the case of $x<0$ and $y<0$, then *for some reason*: $xy>0$.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use the principle of explosion in my proof since we have not discussed it yet. Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: @Richie . You just need to show that $E$ must be true when $A\lor B\lor C\lor D$ is true (ie when either one among the *two that are not contradictions* holds).